# Why does `git branch -r` still show the branch after deleting it locally?

Tags: git, branch, git-bash, git-branch

I have a local branch `add-importerror` that I want to delete:

[image]

To do this, I followed the `git branch -d <BRANCH-NAME>`, based on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely). However, after having seemingly removed the branch, it still shows when I run `git branch -r`.

Why is this? And how can I remove it so that it won't show anymore?

[image]

Comment: You need to delete a **local remote-tracking branch**: `git branch -dr origin/add-importerror`

Comment: this comment above is the actual answer

Comment: I see this question as slightly different to the 'already has an answer' - I see this about the fact that despite a branch not existing on the remote it still shows as that when doing 'git -r' - what is needed is 'git fetch --prune'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the -r option refers to remote, so even though you deleted it locally, you are showing the remote branches.